# Unoffical upgrade Windows 7 RC Ultimate to Windows 7 RTM Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

Anyone here who did this before? I found [this Tutorial](http://rumahabi.com/guide-to-upgrade-windows-7-rc-ultimate-to-windows-7-rtm-enterprise.html) but it just don't work.

Any help is appreciated,
rAyt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use easy transfer to back up your data and do a clean install

What you're trying to do is unsupported by Microsoft and I'm sure they made it hard to do.

On top of that your changing the software version, which won't go well probably:

> Windows 7 Enterprise can only be
> activated with a Volume License MAK or
> KMS key if it is not activated against
> a local KMS server. Enterprise
> requires a VL KMS/MAK out of the box
> or activation against a local KMS
> server. It can be rearmed up to 3
> times.

How-To-Geek also [wrote a post](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3075/how-to-upgrade-the-windows-7-rc-to-rtm/) about doing what you're asking but in the end he notes:

> There are a few important things to
> keep in mind when you are upgrading to
> the final version:
>
> The Windows 7 beta or RC releases were
> Ultimate edition, so you’ll only be
> able to upgrade to the RTM (final) if
> you are installing Ultimate Edition.
> Whenever possible, you should really
> backup your files and do a clean
> install. There are less headaches this
> way, and you get the benefit of a nice
> clean profile.

Note: I know your not asking for this answer, but the worst that can happen is that you loose some settings and have to reinstall some applications. However, everyone using the RC will have to do a clean install

Comment: Ultimate and Enterprise are essentially the same edition.

Comment: Well, I looked into Easy Transfer and honestly, I don't like it.

Comment: Yet again another comment: I've got my license from MSDN AA :)

Comment: It probably depends on how you handle files with Windows, if you have your documents on a seperate partition you don't need it. Being a super user, I would assume you have most of your settings backed up somewhere anyway...

Comment: I've got them in my Dropbox :)

Comment: I understand it's not the answer you want to hear, but it's probably the best...

Answer (score 1):

An upgrade across "milestones" is not officially supported by Microsoft, so any article you find like this is very risky to use and not recommended. I would just use the built-in [**Windows Easy Transfer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Easy_Transfer) to keep files and settings then do a fresh install as recommended.

Microsoft also stated that upgrades to Windows 7 from the following operating systems are not supported:

- Windows 95, Windows 98, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows XP, Windows Vista RTM, Windows Vista Starter, Windows 7 M3, Windows 7 Beta, Windows 7 RC, or Windows 7 IDS
- Windows NT Server 4.0, Windows 2000 Server, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, or Windows Server 2008 R2
- Cross-architecture in-place upgrades (for example, x86 to x64) are not supported.
- Cross-language in-place upgrades (for example, en-us to de-de) are not supported.
- Cross-SKU upgrades (for example, Windows 7 N to Windows 7 K) are not supported.
- Upgrades from Windows Vista to Windows N, Windows K, Windows KN, or Windows E are not supported.
- Cross-build type in-place upgrades (for example, fre to chk) are not supported.
- Pre-release in-place upgrades across milestones (for example, Windows 7 RC to Windows 7 RTM) are not supported.

Further reading in the [Windows 7 Upgrade Paths.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e170eba1-5bab-401f-bbf5-00f0ee7fe0fb)